# How to Prove this Double-Sided Trigonometric Integral Inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

How can I prove this inequality?

> $$\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{1+\frac{sin^2(x)}{2}} dx \leq \frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$$

I don't know how to start this problem, I tried to compute the integral but it is difficult for me.

Can someone help me to prove this? Thank you for your time.

Comment: For the first, don't compute the integral, just note that if $f(x)$ is the integrand (the thing we are integrating), we have $1\le f(x)\le \sqrt{3/2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on @AndreNicolas's comment, we can see that the graph of$$\sqrt{1+\frac{\sin^2(x)}{2}}$$ lies in between the boxes defined by $y=1$ and $y= \sqrt{3/2}$; thus its integral is greater than the area of the first box which is $(height)*(width) = 1\times \pi/2$ and the area of the second box $(height)*(width) = \sqrt{3/2} \times \pi/2.$

This is just a specific case of the general result: $f \le g \le h$ on $[a,b]$ implies that $$\int_a^b f(x) dx \le \int_a^b g(x) dx \le \int_a^b h(x) dx$$

[image]